# Would a qual question tag be useful?

Tags: support, tagging

I'm studying for quals/prelims. Tests you take in your first year or two of PhD (at least in America). Sometimes I want to browse problems that *specifically came up in some qualifying/preliminary exam*.

When I look for "measure theory" there are elementary or high level questions mixed in with the types of problems you would see on a qual. Should we create a new tag or is there I way I can personally filter to see *just problems that could come up on a qual*?

Comment: This older discussion is - to some extent - related: [Tag request: csir-net-exam](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21837/tag-request-csir-net-exam). There exist somewhat similar tags ([tag:gre-exam]) and ([tag:gmat-exam]). Personally I do not think these tags are useful.

Comment: Or perhaps your question is closer to [Sophistication level tags?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/sophistication-level-tags) Some other posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2089) might be of interest in connection with this, too.

Comment: And you might be also interested in these question on main: [Qual question archives?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81138/qual-question-archives) and [phd qualifying exams](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267554/phd-qualifying-exams).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 8):

"The types of problems you would see on a qual" only makes sense if one has a particular educational system in mind. One country's graduate qual is another's undergraduate exam. The level varies a lot within the same country, too.

Even assuming we all agree on what a "qual problem" means, the tag wouldn't achieve the goal. Users posting qual content will not think of tagging their questions this way; also, some if not most of qual-level problems will be asked not in the context of a qual.

In conclusion, this meta-tag would muddy the tagging waters while failing to achieve any of its goals, as [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) did earlier.

Comment: Can you answer the second part of my question?

Comment: Well... that's what happen when you leave a sandwich in a bucket of water for a few days. You get soup.

Comment: @Asaf: it's "goop", actually, not "soup". :) One is tastier than the other.

Comment: @J.M.: I'm philosophically opposed to the idea of soup. It is the bastard child of food and drinks, and I am not okay with that. The only soup for me is fermented bread soup, by which I mean beer, of course.

Comment: @J.M.: Also, as the lovely saying goes... [soup is good food...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUpidCc7wwY)