# Create algebraic dynamics tag and make it a synonym for arithmetic dynamics?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Is it a good idea to create a tag called "algebraic-dynamics" and make it a tag synonym for [arithmetic-dynamics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic-dynamics)?

Note that the current text (good for a quick impression, but probably needs expanding) for the arithmetic dynamics tag is:

> Arithmetic dynamics combines the study of dynamical systems with number theory.

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/187564/118539) on what is algebraic dynamics. In my answer to it, I note that Silverman writes that there is **no firm line between arithmetic dynamics and algebraic dynamics** in his *The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems*, Springer 2007.
[emphasis mine]

Comment: If this question should be posted as an "answer" on the [Tag management 2020](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020) question, please let me know - or just go ahead and delete it and repost it there.

Comment: In my opinion, whether or not something should be posted as a separate question or in the tag management thread is always a judgement call. If you expect the discussion to be longer (e.g., if the question is nuanced or there are several possible options what could be done), then it might be better to have a separate question. (An answer gives less space to post a feedback - since the space in comments is limited.) Advantage of a separate question is also a better visibility, a disadvantage might be that if there are too many tag related questions, people might get fed up with them.

Comment: For what it's worth, sister site Math Overflow currently has 8 questions tagged algebraic dynamics and 28 questions tagged arithmetic dynamics.

Comment: I see there is a downvote - presumably against the idea of creating a new algebraic-dynamics tag and/or making it a tag synonym of arithmetic-dynamics. That's fine, of course, but I would like to know the reasoning in a comment or answer if possible.