# Enlarging the scope of the epsilon-delta tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [epsilon-delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epsilon-delta) tag is used for questions about limits and continuity which use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of such concepts. However, it is sometimes also used for a slightly different subject, namely the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of limit of a sequence, as it happened with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3631349/446262). In my opinion, this is a reasonable option and I propose that the information concerning that tag asserts that it can be used for that purpose. I would like to know what the other members of this community think about that.

Comment: My impression is that the tag is often used in this way, for example, you can have a look at the questions tagged [epsilon-delta+sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epsilon-delta+sequences-and-series).

Comment: Sounds fine, go ahead and edit it into the tag if you like.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber It's done now. Thank you.

Comment: I had a teacher who used the term "epsilonics" to cover all such situations. Sadly I don't think it is well enough known for us to use it as a tag in place of "$\epsilon$ - $\delta$", but I wish it were.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I fully agree that it would be a great name for the tag if it was more well-known.

Comment: How about "limit-definition"? Obviously we would have to keep [tag:epsilon-delta] as a synonym.

Comment: @user771918 That's a nice suggestion. I suggest that you post it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, but I haven't signed up, and can't post in meta. Maybe you could do it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I’m doing this correctly; I don’t respond on Meta very often other than voting.

I think this is a great extension of the tag. I also would like to say that if the description of the tag has been edited to encompass “limits . . . of sequences,” then the tag itself should reflect this. I propose it be changed to `epsilon-delta/epsilon-N` or something similar. This would also encourage people to use the tag for sequences more. For example, I *just* asked a question to which this new tag is highly relevant.