# Should (convergence-divergence) include divergence/convergence of integrals?

Tags: discussion, tagging

According to [the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/convergence-divergence/info), [convergence-divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence-divergence) is intended for convergence/divergence of sequences and series. Here is the revision history for the [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/145353/revisions) and the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/145352/revisions).

However, in practice the tag is used also in connection with [improper integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). You can find plenty of posts tagged [convergence-divergence+improper-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence-divergence+improper-integrals) ([past questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1231721/questions-which-no-longer-have-given-two-tags-including-the-editor?tag1=convergence-divergence&tag2=improper-integrals), [deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1098355/deleted-questions-having-the-given-two-tags?tag1=convergence-divergence&tag2=improper-integrals)
) or [convergence-divergence+integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence-divergence+integration) ([past questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1231721/questions-which-no-longer-have-given-two-tags-including-the-editor?tag1=convergence-divergence&tag2=integration)
[deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1098355/deleted-questions-having-the-given-two-tags?tag1=convergence-divergence&tag2=integration)).

It could be useful to decide whether or not integrals belong under the [convergence-divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence-divergence) tag. And, depending on the outcome of the discussion, either update the tag-info or retag some older posts which do not belong here.

**Question:** Does divergence and convergence of improper integrals belong under the [convergence-divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence-divergence) tag?

---

As a side note, I will also mention that the tag [divergence-operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence-operator) still needs some clean-up, since it was used in many questions concerning convergence and divergence of series and of integrals. Many questions which have this tag alongside
[convergence-divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence-operator+convergence-divergence),
[sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence-operator+sequences-and-series),
[integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence-operator+integration) or
[improper-integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence-operator+improper-integrals) are likely in the need of retagging. For those questions that are related to integrals, it might be useful to know first whether [convergence-divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence-divergence) belongs to those questions, too. (This tag was originally called just [divergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergence). It was renamed [in December 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/renaming-the-divergence-tag), the new name is less likely to be used incorrectly.)

Comment: I will mention that I am aware of the [tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/tag-management-2020). I opted for a separate post, since my expectation is that this might required a longer discussion (and comments under an answer in the tag management thread would not provide sufficient space).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, yes. Because there are related approaches (the comparison test) to convergence of integrals and convergence of series, besides the existence of the integral test for series.

Comment: It seems unlikely that there will be more feedback on this. I have edited the tag-info a bit - of course, further improvements of the tag-info are more than welcome.